# Les ringards de sa folie

Tags: sens, paroles-de-chanson

From Brel's « [Les remparts de Varsovie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uayaj3FA5IM) » :

> Madame promène son cul sur les remparts de Varsovie
> Madame promène son cœur sur les ringards de sa folie
> Madame promène son ombre sur les grand-places de l'Italie
> Je trouve que Madame vit sa vie

Mostly interpretable. But for the second line:

(1) How do you understand « les ringards » ? It would seem to mean those who are old-fashioned. My take on the promèn-ing of her heart on them is that she's just seeing the sights of love, flirting without the intention of commitment. So what does old-fashioned-ness have to do with that? Maybe they're the small-timers? Those who, not being part of the "in crowd", matter little in the long run?

(2) How do you parse « de sa folie » ? I take it as something like « coup de folie », i.e. she does these actions on a whim, in a flight of fancy. But I can also see it syntactically attaching to « les ringards », perhaps meaning « qu'elle a choisi dans sa folie ».

Comment: Un ringard c'est aussi une barre de fer... mais je n'irai pas non plus de ce côté là. On est dans la poésie et parfois il ne faut pas chercher trop loin. C'est le genre de cas où je dirais que toute interprétation est personnelle et subjective et il aurait fallu demander à l'auteur ! Quite interesting to see how all the translations of the song into English differ, most just skip the problem, [one](https://cagibilit.com/translating-jacques-brel-by-michele-herman/) makes a real effort to try and make sense !

Comment: Vu le contexte, la « Folle du cul » a des ‘nostalgies’ sur les piètres amours passées.

Comment: En fait, c'est assez transparent: les _ringards de sa folie_ sont juste les pauvres types avec lesquels, dans sa "folie" elle a des relations.

Answer (score 1):

The song is obviously directed at someone Brel knew or is a collage of extravagances in women he knew. But the poetic, rythm-dictated verses  and number of double-entendres make it difficult to tell the exact  meaning without knowing the historical details of their relationship - and even more challenging to translate.

The intended meaning of *ringard* here is most likely:

> (Personne) incapable, médiocre

https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ringard B.1.a)

An attempt at translating the verse could be something like

"Madame fancies their dorky sycophancy"

"Madame runs her heart over the fools of her mad court"

"Madame lets her heart loose among the buffoons of her farce"

Comment: En fait, c'est assez transparent: les _ringards de sa folie_ sont just les pauvres types avec lesquels, dans sa "folie" elle a des relations.